# AWS Sagemaker, InvokeEndpoint operation, Model error: pass an offload_folder for model submodules?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

So, I deployed 2 sagemaker endpoints (of Large Language Models) following their AWS official tutorial notebook here: https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/jumpstart-foundation-models/question_answering_retrieval_augmented_generation/question_answering_langchain_jumpstart.ipynb however, I am unable to invoke the endpoints for inference due to a weird error that keeps asking for an offload folder. My notebook instance uses `ml.g5.xlarge`. Below are the codes, where I set the model config, deploy the endpoints and and try to invoke the endpoint for inference.

The functions, I even edited the `query_endpoint_with_json_payload()` function by including the offload_folder parameter:

```
def query_endpoint_with_json_payload(encoded_json, endpoint_name, content_type="application/json", offload_folder=None):
    client = boto3.client("runtime.sagemaker")
    if offload_folder is not None:
        response = client.invoke_endpoint(
            EndpointName=endpoint_name, ContentType=content_type, Body=encoded_json, CustomAttributes=f'{{"offload_folder":"{offload_folder}"}}'
        )
    else:
        response = client.invoke_endpoint(
        EndpointName=endpoint_name,
        ContentType=content_type,
        Body=encoded_json
        )
    return response


def parse_response_model_flan_t5(query_response):
    model_predictions = json.loads(query_response["Body"].read())
    generated_text = model_predictions["generated_texts"]
    return generated_text


def parse_response_multiple_texts_bloomz(query_response):
    generated_text = []
    model_predictions = json.loads(query_response["Body"].read())
    for x in model_predictions[0]:
        generated_text.append(x["generated_text"])
    return generated_text
```

Model Configuration:

```
_MODEL_CONFIG_ = {
    "huggingface-text2text-flan-t5-xxl": {
        "instance type": "ml.g5.xlarge",
        "env": {"SAGEMAKER_MODEL_SERVER_WORKERS": "1", "TS_DEFAULT_WORKERS_PER_MODEL": "1"},
        "parse_function": parse_response_model_flan_t5,
        "prompt": """Answer based on context:\n\n{context}\n\n{question}""",
    },
    "huggingface-textembedding-gpt-j-6b": {
        "instance type": "ml.g5.xlarge",
        "env": {"SAGEMAKER_MODEL_SERVER_WORKERS": "1", "TS_DEFAULT_WORKERS_PER_MODEL": "1"},
    },
}
```

Deployment:

```
newline, bold, unbold = "\n", "\033[1m", "\033[0m"

for model_id in _MODEL_CONFIG_:
    endpoint_name = name_from_base(f"jumpstart-example-raglc-{model_id}")
    inference_instance_type = _MODEL_CONFIG_[model_id]["instance type"]
    #offload_folder = _MODEL_CONFIG_[model_id].get("offload_folder")  # Get the offload folder for the model

    # Retrieve the inference container uri. This is the base HuggingFace container image for the default model above.
    deploy_image_uri = image_uris.retrieve(
        region=None,
        framework=None,  # automatically inferred from model_id
        image_scope="inference",
        model_id=model_id,
        model_version=model_version,
        instance_type=inference_instance_type,
    )
    # Retrieve the model uri.
    model_uri = model_uris.retrieve(
        model_id=model_id, model_version=model_version, model_scope="inference"
    )
    model_inference = Model(
        image_uri=deploy_image_uri,
        model_data=model_uri,
        role=aws_role,
        predictor_cls=Predictor,
        name=endpoint_name,
        env=_MODEL_CONFIG_[model_id]["env"],
    )
    model_predictor_inference = model_inference.deploy(
        initial_instance_count=1,
        instance_type=inference_instance_type,
        predictor_cls=Predictor,
        endpoint_name=endpoint_name,
        #offload_folder=offload_folder,
    )
    print(f"{bold}Model {model_id} has been deployed successfully.{unbold}{newline}")
    _MODEL_CONFIG_[model_id]["endpoint_name"] = endpoint_name
```

The models were deployed successfully, however, invoking the endpoints to run inference fails. Here is the code to invoke the endpoints together with the payload:

```
question = "Which instances can I use with Managed Spot Training in SageMaker?"
payload = {
    "text_inputs": question,
    "max_length": 100,
    "num_return_sequences": 1,
    "top_k": 50,
    "top_p": 0.95,
    "do_sample": True,
}

list_of_LLMs = list(_MODEL_CONFIG_.keys())
list_of_LLMs.remove("huggingface-textembedding-gpt-j-6b")  # remove the embedding model

offload_folder = "s3://ragbucketfo/offload/"
for model_id in list_of_LLMs:
    endpoint_name = _MODEL_CONFIG_[model_id]["endpoint_name"]
    query_response = query_endpoint_with_json_payload(
        json.dumps(payload).encode("utf-8"), endpoint_name=endpoint_name, offload_folder=offload_folder
    )
    generated_texts = _MODEL_CONFIG_[model_id]["parse_function"](query_response)
    print(f"For model: {model_id}, the generated output is: {generated_texts[0]}\n")
```

The error I get back is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModelError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[55], line 16
     14 for model_id in list_of_LLMs:
     15     endpoint_name = _MODEL_CONFIG_[model_id]["endpoint_name"]
---> 16     query_response = query_endpoint_with_json_payload(
     17         json.dumps(payload).encode("utf-8"), endpoint_name=endpoint_name, offload_folder=offload_folder
     18     )
     19     generated_texts = _MODEL_CONFIG_[model_id]["parse_function"](query_response)
     20     print(f"For model: {model_id}, the generated output is: {generated_texts[0]}\n")

Cell In[51], line 4, in query_endpoint_with_json_payload(encoded_json, endpoint_name, content_type, offload_folder)
      2 client = boto3.client("runtime.sagemaker")
      3 if offload_folder is not None:
----> 4     response = client.invoke_endpoint(
      5         EndpointName=endpoint_name, ContentType=content_type, Body=encoded_json, CustomAttributes=f'{{"offload_folder":"{offload_folder}"}}'
      6     )
      7 else:
      8     response = client.invoke_endpoint(
      9     EndpointName=endpoint_name,
     10     ContentType=content_type,
     11     Body=encoded_json
     12     )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py:530, in ClientCreator._create_api_method.<locals>._api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    526     raise TypeError(
    527         f"{py_operation_name}() only accepts keyword arguments."
    528     )
    529 # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 530 return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py:964, in BaseClient._make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    962     error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    963     error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 964     raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    965 else:
    966     return parsed_response

ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{
  "code": 400,
  "type": "InternalServerException",
  "message": "At least one of the model submodule will be offloaded to disk, please pass along an `offload_folder`."
}
". See https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-west-2#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/jumpstart-example-raglc-huggingface-tex-2023-07-23-04-36-50-245 in account 367332732143 for more information.
```

I have tried different instances including `ml.g5.4xlarge` but this instance only allows for one deployment (so I couldn't deploy both models). Even when I deploy only the `huggingface-text2text-flan-t5-xxl` model, on `ml.g5.4xlarge` I run into the CUDA issue below

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModelError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_12905/510372874.py in <cell line: 14>()
     14 for model_id in list_of_LLMs:
     15     endpoint_name = _MODEL_CONFIG_[model_id]["endpoint_name"]
---> 16     query_response = query_endpoint_with_json_payload(
     17         json.dumps(payload).encode("utf-8"), endpoint_name=endpoint_name
     18     )

/tmp/ipykernel_12905/111908580.py in query_endpoint_with_json_payload(encoded_json, endpoint_name, content_type)
      1 def query_endpoint_with_json_payload(encoded_json, endpoint_name, content_type="application/json"):
      2     client = boto3.client("runtime.sagemaker")
----> 3     response = client.invoke_endpoint(
      4         EndpointName=endpoint_name, ContentType=content_type, Body=encoded_json
      5     )

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    528                 )
    529             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 530             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    531 
    532         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    962             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    963             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 964             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    965         else:
    966             return parsed_response

ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{
  "code": 400,
  "type": "InternalServerException",
  "message": "Attempting to deserialize object on CUDA device 1 but torch.cuda.device_count() is 1. Please use torch.load with map_location to map your storages to an existing device."
}
". See https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-west-2#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/jumpstart-example-raglc-huggingface-tex-2023-07-23-02-44-12-269 in account 367332732143 for more information.```
````

I would really appreciate your guidance. Once again is the link to the tutorial notebook by AWS:https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/jumpstart-foundation-models/question_answering_retrieval_augmented_generation/question_answering_langchain_jumpstart.ipynb

Comment: Have you tried deploying to the exact instance types? I was able to run the notebook successfully if I didn't update the instances.

Comment: thanks @durga_sury, thanks for your reply. Yes, I had earlier tried using the exact instance types specified in the notebooks i.e 'ml.g5.12xlarge' and 'ml.g5.24xlarge', however, I couldn't deploy the embeddings model to the 'ml.g5.24xlarge' instance. resource limit is always exceeded whenever I try.

Comment: Gotcha, if resource limit exceeds, you can increase it through service quotas (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/latest/userguide/intro.html) You can go to Service Quotas on your AWS console, find the `ml.g5.24xlarge` training instance limit, and increase it. I tried it with different instances and it fails - I suspect it's to do with the GPU settings in the notebook.

Comment: Try changing the kernel to data science and python 3. Data Science 2 and 3 gave me similar errors.

Comment: Hi @navule, how do I find these kernels, I see conda python, pytorch p10, etc but no Data Science 1 or 2, etc.

Comment: You can find for kernel at the top right of the notebook. Clicking on it should open an image like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkIm1.png

Comment: @MustaphaUnubiMomoh, Any luck with the inference?